# Filter content based on checked radio button's label text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code which filters contents based on checked radio button's value, I want to turn it to checked radio button's label text. Here is the code below;

```js
$(function() {
  var $filters = $("input:radio");
  var $categoryContent = $('#mainhide div');

  $filters.click(function() {
    $categoryContent.hide();
    var $selectedFilters = $(this).closest('ul').find(':radio').filter(':checked');
    $categoryContent.filter(':contains(' + $selectedFilters.val() + ')').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="cdg">
      <input type="radio" id="cdg" name="type" value="brand1" />brand1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdh">
      <input type="radio" id="cdh" name="type" value="brand2" />brand2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdi">
      <input type="radio" id="cdi" name="type" value="brand3" />brand3</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="cdj">
      <input type="radio" id="cdj" name="quantity" value="10" />10</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdk">
      <input type="radio" id="cdk" name="quantity" value="20" />20</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdl">
      <input type="radio" id="cdl" name="quantity" value="30" />30</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="mainhide">
  <div>brand1 in stock - 10</div>
  <div>brand2 in stock - 20</div>
  <div>brand3 in stock - 30</div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so when I check any radio button the content in `#mainhide div` should show according to the selected radio button's label text.

Comment: Your code appears to be doing what you describe already. Do you have an issue with it?

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan , No its not doing the way I want. I am working on this http://lacoliquid-sample.webflow.io/  and I want to filter the text blocks below those radio buttons according to the selection of those radio buttons. There are 4 different radio button groups (you can see all by click on "All" button on top). Currently it shows the text of last clicked/checked radio button and its not working like a filter should work.

Answer (score 0):

Update your current script with these two lines.

So it returns the selected input as it does now, finds the parent and then gets the label text. Because of the white space, we then use trim.

```
var lbl = $selectedFilters.parent().text();

$categoryContent.filter(':contains(' + $.trim(lbl) + ')').show();
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/rLkAbv

Comment: Thanks it works, actually I am trying to make a radio button filter here; http://lacoliquid-sample.webflow.io/
There are multiple radio button groups and I want the content should should that bears content from all these radio groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like :

```
$("input[name=type]:checked").val()
$("input[name=quantity]:checked").val()
```

```js
function init() {
  $("#brandName").text($("input[name=type]:checked").val());
  $("#qty").text($("input[name=quantity]:checked").val());
}
$(function() {
  init();
  $("input[type=radio]").click(init);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="cdg">
      <input type="radio" id="cdg" name="type" value="brand1" checked />brand1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdh">
      <input type="radio" id="cdh" name="type" value="brand2" />brand2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdi">
      <input type="radio" id="cdi" name="type" value="brand3" />brand3</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="cdj">
      <input type="radio" id="cdj" name="quantity" value="10" checked />10</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdk">
      <input type="radio" id="cdk" name="quantity" value="20" />20</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="cdl">
      <input type="radio" id="cdl" name="quantity" value="30" />30</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="content"><span id="brandName"></span> in stock - <span id="qty"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to filter using radio button value, I want to filter using label text.

Comment: Or, can you please tell how can I set radio button value to whatever its label text is?